# Cannot get 'Or' operator to work inside a dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been using R (RStudio) for a couple of weeks now, and I've run across a problem I don't know how to explain. I also can't find a mention of it online anywhere, and my code appears to adhere to the standards set by most of the online self-help guides. This is very likely related to my limited understanding of R. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm reading in an Excel spreadsheet ( `dataInput <- readxl::read_xlsx('demo.xlsx')` ), which is then stored as a tibble, like so (this is demonstration data only):

```
   Val  Colour Range  Rate
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA red       10   0.1
2    NA blue       2   0.2
3     1 green      3   0.3
4     1 red       NA   0.4
5     0 blue       5   0.5
6     0 green      4   0.6
7     3 red        6  NA  
8     3 blue       7   0.7
```

I want to use `dplyr::filter` to filter out any rows from this tibble in which `Val` is NA or 0, and then select specified columns. To do so, my code looks like this:

```
dataOutput <- dplyr::filter(dataInput, Val != 0 | Val != "") %>%
              dplyr::select(c(Val, Colour, Rate))
```

I've assumed that the use of the 'or' operator would mean that rows in `Val` which contain 0, or are empty, would be removed, and so my output tibble would look like this:

```
   Val  Colour  Rate
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 green    0.3
2     1 red      0.4
3     3 red     NA  
4     3 blue     0.7
```

*Instead*, the R code appears to produce something in which the empty rows in `Val` are removed, but *not* rows containing 0:

```
   Val  Colour  Rate
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 green    0.3
2     1 red      0.4
3     0 blue     0.5
4     0 green    0.6
5     3 red     NA  
6     3 blue     0.7
```

I can achieve the desired effect by making two separate lines of code within the pipe, like so --

```
dataOutput <- dplyr::filter(dataInput, Val != 0) %>%
              dplyr::filter(Val != "") %>%
              dplyr::select(c(Val, Colour, Rate))
```

-- or, weirdly, by using the `&` operator rather than the `|` operator, but I'm concerned that if I'm misunderstanding something it could be causing problems in my data that I don't know how to spot. This would mean I can't trust the output from my script.

RStudio isn't throwing up any error messages, but this behaviour is consistent regardless of what dataset I use, or even which columns I'm trying to filter (whether it's the same column or two different columns). Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I think you might achieve the same by doing filter(!Val %in% c(0, ""))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `is.na()`, since you're trying to detect NA values, not empty strings.

Your logic currently says `give me the rows that are either not equal to 0 OR are not empty`. Rows that contain `0` are not empty, so they satisfy the latter condition and stay in your data.

You want instead `give me the rows that are not equal to 0 AND are not NA`.

```
dataOutput <- dplyr::filter(dataInput, Val != 0 & !is.na(Val)) %>%
              dplyr::select(c(Val, Colour, Rate))
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Unfortunately, when I make this change, I'm still getting an output tibble with 6 rows instead of 4 -- the rows containing 0 are still present.

Comment: Do you have the `&` in the first row? My initial answer still had the `|` operator, but I edited that.

Comment: Here is the code exactly as I ran it: `dataOutput <- dplyr::filter(dataInput, Val != 0 | !is.na(Val)) %>%  dplyr::select(c(Val, Colour, Rate))`. (I appreciate you trying to figure this out with me, by the way.)

Comment: Ah yes, change that `|` to `&` as in my current answer. That was a mistake in my initial answer - apologies.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you, and good catch! A quick question: if I were to do this same filter, but looking at two different columns (`Val != 0`, as well as `Rate != 0.3`, for example), would this also require the ampersand? Just trying to make sure I understand the logic.

Comment: Yes, doesn't matter if you look at a different column, you want the ampersand. Best thing to do is read it aloud. `Give me rows where Val does not equal 0 OR Rate does not equal 0.3`: that would return the whole dataset, since every row satisfies at least one of those conditions. If you say `AND`, it would remove 5 rows, since there are five rows that fail at least one of those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataOutput <- dplyr::filter(dataInput, !Val %in% c(0, ""))
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this switches the problem I have -- rows containing `0` are removed, but not rows containing `NA`.